# How to connect in MS sql server using php

Tags: php, sql-server

How do you connect to sql server using php?

```
$server = "MySQLSERVER";

$conn = mysqli_connect($server,'sa','11111111');

if (!$conn) 
{
    die("Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL");
}
```

This code gives the result:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host 'kpadilla.rafi.local' is
>   not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\sample\sample.php on line 5

Comment: Have you tried to use a famos tool named Google?

Comment: I think `kpadilla.rafi.local` is not allowed to connect...

Comment: MariaDB has little to do with MicroSoft SQL Server ...

Comment: First of all, $server should be localhost - not MySQLSERVER. Also, mysqli_connect needs 4 params, not 3. The first one is the sql server (normally localhost - if you're working with xampp localhost for sure), the second is the user, the 3rd the password, and the 4th (missing in your code) is the name of the database. http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Answer (score 0):

You must be use [`mssql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php) function instead of `mysqli_connect`, because you try to connect ***MSSQL Server***. (First installing mssql extenstion: http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.installation.php)

```
$conn = mssql_connect($server,'sa','11111111');

if (!$conn) 
{
    die("Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use mssql_connect:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.mssql-connect.php

```
$conn = mssql_connect($server, $user, $password);
```